# Docker-compose volume error: incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker-compose yml file which is giving me the following error:

`ERROR: Volume <path>db:/db:rw has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]`

I've seen multiple posts about this issue but never a resolution. Working on macOS with the following yml file:

```
volumes:
  db:
  rdb:

services:
  volumes-provisioner:
    image: hasnat/volumes-provisioner
    environment:
      PROVISION_DIRECTORIES: "1001:1001:0755:/db"
    volumes:
      - "./db:/db:rw"
  volumes-provisioner2:
    image: hasnat/volumes-provisioner
    environment:
      PROVISION_DIRECTORIES: "999:999:0755:/data"
    volumes:
      - "./rdb:/data:rw"
  redis:
    image: "redislabs/redisgraph:2.2.6"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "./rdb:/data:rw"
    depends_on:
      - volumes-provisioner2
  insight:
    image: "redislabs/redisinsight:1.7.1"
    depends_on:
      - volumes-provisioner
      - redis
    volumes:
      - "./db:/db:rw"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was running `docker-compose` from a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) terminal running on Windows. If I run `docker-compose` from Windows Powershell, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your version of docker. Make sure you've upgraded to latest, then add a docker version statement to the top of your file (version: "3.9"). I've modified your file below to include this, and I also removed the quotes around the images. After that it works.

```
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  db:
  rdb:

services:
  volumes-provisioner:
    image: hasnat/volumes-provisioner
    environment:
      PROVISION_DIRECTORIES: "1001:1001:0755:/db"
    volumes:
      - "./db:/db:rw"
  volumes-provisioner2:
    image: hasnat/volumes-provisioner
    environment:
      PROVISION_DIRECTORIES: "999:999:0755:/data"
    volumes:
      - "./rdb:/data:rw"
  redis:
    image: redislabs/redisgraph:2.2.6
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "./rdb:/data:rw"
    depends_on:
      - volumes-provisioner2
  insight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight:1.7.1
    depends_on:
      - volumes-provisioner
      - redis
    volumes:
      - "./db:/db:rw"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a shot..I realized my homebrew was way out of date (some shallow clone) which also updated docker, docker compose, and everything in between..will let you know!