# Mount volume with docker-compose has incorrect format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I am learning about docker and docker compose and I am facing the next issue when I try to run `docker-compose up`.

Let me show my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/ningx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

And this is the error I face:

```
nginx.conf:/etc/ningx/conf.d/default.conf:ro has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]
```

Things I tried:

I came acrross to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805841/docker-compose-volume-error-incorrect-format-should-be-externalinternalmode) but I tried what was mentioned with the version label but I got similar output.

I have cheked the documentation and all looks fine.

I have latest versions:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:54:27 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.6
  Git commit:       75249d8
  Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:52:33 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.9
  GitCommit:        e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1
  GitCommit:        v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.7.10
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
```

The file `nginx.conf` exists and I am launching the command from the right directory.

Comment: Hm, I see a small typo, and unless you were typing it then that could be your issue. The second part, `/etc/ningx/conf.d/default.conf`, says `ningx` which probably does not exist and should be `etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

All right, after trying a few more things, I ended up finding the issue. The issue was that the absolute path where these files were located contained a semicolon `:`.

Basically, this is from a udemy course and I named the parent folder as the name of the course.

I would remove the question but maybe it can help to someone in the future.

Thanks.